# How can I make VS code read both Django and html in a .html file? Whenever I install the django extension on vs code it stops reading html

Tags: html, django, visual-studio-code

I have tried putting this in my settings.json file-

```
{

"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"emmet.includeLanguages": {"django-html": "html"},
"files.associations": {
    "**/templates/*.html": "django-html",
    "**/templates/*": "django-txt",
    "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements",
    "*.html": "html"
  }}
```

But it makes no changes vs code still only reads Django and not html. I am unable to get closing tags or autocomplete for html. I have tried every solution available on the internet but none works. Although every time I uninstall the django extension from vs code it starts reading html code again. I have tried all methods available on the internet but none work, sometimes it only read html and sometimes only django. Please help

Answer (score 0):

According to [Django Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=batisteo.vscode-django) (I suppose you are using this one), below **Usage** section the appropriate settings to set are:

```
"files.associations": {
    "**/*.html": "html",
    "**/templates/**/*.html": "django-html",
    "**/templates/**/*": "django-txt",
    "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements"
},
```

**Note:** Copy and replace the code above with yours (which I think is the cause to your problem).

If you wanna take advantage of [emmet](https://emmet.io), you should add the line below to your **settings.json**:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {"django-html": "html"},
```

**Note**: I don't think setting `"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab"` to `true` is doing anything in your case.

Besides, **django-html** documents doesn't seem to get formatted properly with [prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) formatter, so I suggest using the settings bellow to format **django-html** using [beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify):

```
"beautify.language": {
    "html": [
        "django-html"
    ]
},
```